# GCM registered device receiving two types of notification

Tags: android, node.js, google-cloud-messaging

I registered my android device using the [example project](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/start) on Google's developer site and only added the configuration file as intended to the project. Now, when I send a notification from my nodeJS server using `node-gcm`, I receive two types of notification:
[image: Notification screenshot]
The notification 'GCM Message' is what the app gets by default if I run the `./gradlew run -Pmsg="<message>"` command in terminal to test it but it isn't blank then. The other notification 'New Chat Message' is what I intend to send.
My problem is that I want to receive only the default notification which isn't blank. How do I fix this?

Code of nodeJS server:

```
message.addNotification('title', 'New Chat Message');
message.addNotification('icon', 'ic_launcher');
message.addNotification('message', 'TEST MESSAGE');
message.addNotification('body', name + ": " + msg);
sender.send(message, {registrationTokens: regTokens}, function (err, response) {
    if (err) console.error(err);
    else    console.log(response);
});
```

Code of Android APP that handles message:

```
public void onMessageReceived(String from, Bundle data) {
    System.out.println("MyGcmListenerService.onMessageReceived");
    String message = data.getString("message");
    if(data.containsKey("body")){
        System.out.println("Contains");
    }
    Log.d(TAG, "From: " + from);
    Log.d(TAG, "Message: " + message);

    if (from.startsWith("/topics/")) {
        // message received from some topic.
    } else {
        // normal downstream message.
    }
    sendNotification(message);
}
```

**EDIT-** In the photo I receive the 'why man' message twice because I sent it twice. There's nothing wrong in it.

**Another Edit-** I just noticed that when my device sleeps or when the app is paused or killed, only then I receive the 2nd type of notification using nodeJS server. But if I run the `gradlew` command in any situation mentioned above, everything works like it should.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed it! The problem was on server side, I was supposed to use `message.addData()` instead of `message.addNotification()`.